# `ssh: connect to host ssh.dev.azure.com port 22: Connection timed out` error

Tags: git, azure, ssh

In my home I created a SSH and cloned the repository by creating a SSH keys.  (`git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/ixo-vx/XXX/XXX.UI`) After I reach office, when I initiate any of the git process, I am getting an error as :

```
ssh: connect to host ssh.dev.azure.com port 22: Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Since I am at office, what is the correct I need to do for this?
In case if I create a new clone using `https` - it clones fine. there is no issue on new, as well https prompts `git` authentication popup. but `ssh` doesn't. How to fix this? what is the update I need to do in office?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May'be it's your corporate firewall issue (it block 22 port connection). Try to connect trough another internet channel.

Comment: But when i run the `git config --get remote.origin.url` - shows all values. I can able to checkout with new folder using `https`

Comment: `https` work over 443 port

Comment: @Tirex - do you mean to get the access for port 22 from corporate services?

Comment: yes, check access with `telnet` for example.

Comment: @Tirex - run this command `telnet 10.232.133.72 22` and got the result as `Connecting To 10.232.133.72...Could not open connection to the host, on port 22: Connect failed` - what it means?

Comment: It looks like your corporate firewall or local firewall on the local machine blocking the outbound traffic for port 22.

Comment: Thanks, shared the same to netwrok team and fixed the issue. very thanks to `Tirex` and `Nancy`..!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just to post the comments as an answer for more references.

In this case, you can use `telnet` to validate the network connectivity from your local machine to the remote SSH host. As a result, you have a Connect failed on port 22 error, just check if the corporate firewall or local firewall on the local machine blocking the outbound traffic for port 22 to fix this issue.

Comment: Could you explain how to use telnet to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I have received this because of **complete network failure**. It was just not obvious via any other symptoms first.

Answer (score 1):

> Could you explain how to use telnet to do this? –
> findusl Apr 11 at 11:19

- Install telnet if you don't have it. Most distros don't add by default (`yum install telnet`, or `apt-get -i telnet` or somehow on Windows) because it carries some security risks. For testing, it's fine.
- Invoke `telnet` with the port you want. For ssh, I want port 22:

```
$ telnet ssh.dev.azure.com 22

Trying 20.37.158.23...
Connected to ssh.dev.azure.com.
Escape character is '^]'.

SSH-2.0-SSHBlackbox.10

Invalid packet size
Connection closed by foreign host.
$
```

It will wait for input, and you can type stuff, since telnet is basically a terminal program that talks over IP. Eventually the target machine will get bored and hang up because you are wasting its time. BUT you have proved the access to that port works. This works for HTTP and POP servers too.